# Instantiate a type that is a TypeVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

As a C++ programmer the following code seems very natural to me but it doesn't run:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List, NewType

TPopMember = TypeVar('TPopMember')
Population = NewType('Population', List[TPopMember])
class EvolutionaryAlgorithm(Generic[TPopMember]):
    def __init__(self, populationSize: int) -> None:
        # The following raises TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not callable
        self.__population = Population([TPopMember() for _ in range(populationSize)])
```

Apparently Python isn't able to instantiate classes (the TPopMember) that are actually TypeVars. I simply want to create a list (Population) with a couple of default initialized (how do you say that in Python?) TPopMembers. How should I go about this?

I'm using Python 3.7.2.

Comment: Keep in mind, that these are only **hints**. I would suggest create a new `class` of TPopMember

Comment: You could pass require a `TPopMember` factory to be passed to `EvolutionaryAlgorithm`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You didn't realize that type hint is a **hint**. In other words, don't think it is a type at all. You can't instantiate them.

As I understand from your comment, your intention is doing what C++ template allows you to do. So here is my way to achieve that:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List, NewType, Type
import random

class PopMember:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 100)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pop({})".format(self.x)

TPopMember = TypeVar("TPopMember")
Population = NewType('Population', List[TPopMember])

class EvolutionaryAlgorithm(Generic[TPopMember]):
    def __init__(self, member_class: Type[TPopMember], populationSize: int) -> None:
        self.__population = Population([member_class() for _ in range(populationSize)])
    def __repr__(self):
        return "EA({})".format(self.__population)

x = EvolutionaryAlgorithm(PopMember, 5)
print(x)
```

output:

```
EA([Pop(49), Pop(94), Pop(24), Pop(73), Pop(66)])
```

What you have to understand is that, if you derived a class from `Generic[T]`, you need to use `T` some how when you create your class. In my example I <del>create a dummy object and resolve its class and initiate it. Normally I would not write in this way, I can just throw in a class as parameber</del> pass in a class to the constructor to request to generate items of this particular type because class itself, distinct from an instance of it, is also a Python object. (thanks chepner for the suggestion)

Comment: 1. My linter does saying: `Value 'Generic' is unsubscriptablepylint(unsubscriptable-object)` but I don't understand why. I'm essentially doing exactly this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types. (I don't see the difference at least).
2. Oke, I understand but the point of the generic thing is that the client code can decide what type TPopMember should be. Any pythonic way to achieve that (besides defining an IPopMember interface class)?

Comment: rewrite the answer

Comment: There's no need to pass an instance of `PopMember` to `__init__`, only to access its `__class__` attribute. Define `__init__(self, member_class: Type[PopMember], ...)`, then pass `PopMember` itself (or any subclass of `PopMember`).

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List, NewType
import random

class PopMember:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 100)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pop({})".format(self.x)

TPopMember = TypeVar('TPopMember')
Population = NewType('Population', List[TPopMember])
class EvolutionaryAlgorithm(Generic[TPopMember]):
    def __init__(self, populationSize: int) -> None:
        obj = self.__orig_class__.__args__[0]
        self.__population = Population([obj() for _ in  range(populationSize)])

    @property
    def population(self):
        return self.__population

evolution = EvolutionaryAlgorithm[PopMember](100)
print(evolution.population)
```

The type used to define the Generic class can be found, within the instance in here: **`self.__orig_class__.__args__[0]`**.

For classmethods just use this -> **`cls.__args__[0]`**

Comment: `__orig_class__` is an internal attribute, it should not be used directly.

Comment: @demberto I know, see the alternative response that I have put below ...

Comment: @demberto Python 3.12 now has `types.get_original_bases(cls)`

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility that avoid problems when serializing classes (ie using pickle).

Instead of using Generic, you can do the following:

```
from typing import Callable, Any
import random
from enum import Enum
from functools import wraps

class PopMember:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 100)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pop({})".format(self.x)

class PapMember:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 200)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pop({})".format(self.x)


def check_type(func: Callable) -> Callable:
    """Decorator to check that the child class has defined the POINT_TYPE member attribute."""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(obj, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        if not hasattr(obj, 'T'):
            raise NotImplementedError(
                "You can not instantiate an abstract class.")
        return func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class EvolutionaryAlgorithm:
    @check_type
    def __init__(self, populationSize: int) -> None:
        self.__population = [self.T() for _ in  range(populationSize)]

    @classmethod
    @check_type
    def create(cls, populationSize: int):
        """Example of classmethod."""
        # You can use T as cls.T
        return cls(populationSize=populationSize)

    @property
    def population(self):
        return self.__population

class EvolutionaryAlgorithmPopMember(EvolutionaryAlgorithm):
    T = PopMember

class EvolutionaryAlgorithmPapMember(EvolutionaryAlgorithm):
    T = PapMember

class EvolutionaryAlgorithmFactory(Enum):
    POP_MEMBER = EvolutionaryAlgorithmPopMember
    PAP_MEMBER = EvolutionaryAlgorithmPapMember

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        return self.value(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


evolution = EvolutionaryAlgorithmFactory.POP_MEMBER(100)
print(evolution.population)
```

This will avoid a lot of problems, rather than hacking python internals.

The main advantage in here is that you can reuse the classmethod functions.

Answer (score 0):

A much easy solution could be to use *functools.partial* in an *enum* factory:

```
import random
from typing import Any
from enum import Enum
from functools import partial

class PopMember:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 100)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pop({})".format(self.x)

class PapMember:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 200)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pap({})".format(self.x)

class EvolutionaryAlgorithm:
    def __init__(self, member_type: Any, populationSize: int) -> None:
        self.__member_type = member_type
        self.__population = [self.__member_type() for _ in  range(populationSize)]

    @property
    def population(self):
        return self.__population

class EvolutionaryAlgorithmFactory(Enum):
    POP_MEMBER = partial(EvolutionaryAlgorithm, PopMember)
    PAP_MEMBER = partial(EvolutionaryAlgorithm, PapMember)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        return self.value(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


evolution = EvolutionaryAlgorithmFactory.POP_MEMBER(100)
print(evolution.population)
```