# Python generic with union

Tags: python, generics, types, subclass, type-hinting

I have a Document and Page types, both containing data and metadata parts. They are looking the same:

```
class Document:
    __data: DocumentData
    __meta: DocumentMeta

    def __init__(self, part: Union[DocumentData, DocumentMeta, None] = None, data: Optional[DocumentData] = None,
             meta: Optional[DocumentMeta] = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.data: Optional[DocumentData] = data
        self.meta: Optional[DocumentMeta] = meta

        if part is not None:
            if type(part) == DocumentData:
                data = part
                meta = DocumentMeta()
            elif type(part) == DocumentMeta:
                meta = part
                data = DocumentData()    

class Page:
    __data: PageData
    __meta: PageMeta

    def __init__(self, part: Union[PageData, PageMeta, None] = None, data: Optional[PageData] = None,
             meta: Optional[PageMeta] = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.data: Optional[PageData] = data
        self.meta: Optional[PageMeta] = meta

        if part is not None:
            if type(part) == PageData:
                data = part
                meta = PageMeta()
            elif type(part) == PageMeta:
                meta = part
                data = PageData()
```

I would like now to refactor these 2 types to use a generic type. I did it that way:

```
from typing import Generic, Optional, TypeVar, Union

DataStruct = TypeVar('DataStruct')
MetaStruct = TypeVar('MetaStruct')


class MetaDataStruct(Generic[DataStruct, MetaStruct]):
    __data: DataStruct
    __meta: MetaStruct

    def __init__(
        self,
        part: Union[DataStruct, MetaStruct, None] = None,
        data: Optional[DataStruct] = None,
        meta: Optional[MetaStruct] = None
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.data: Optional[DataStruct] = data
        self.meta: Optional[MetaStruct] = meta

        if part is not None:
            if type(part) == DataStruct:
                data = part
                meta = MetaStruct()
            elif type(part) == MetaStruct:
                meta = part
                data = DataStruct()


class DocumentData:
    pass


class DocumentMeta:
    pass


class PageData:
    pass


class PageMeta:
    pass


class Document(MetaDataStruct[DocumentData, DocumentMeta]):
    pass


class Page(MetaDataStruct[PageData, PageMeta]):
    pass
```

Now there's few problems with type checking.

1. *if type(part) == DataStruct:* returns False all the time. In runtime a type(part) is one of: DocumentData, DocumentMeta, PageData, PageMeta. I understand that I have to compare type(part) with actual type of DataStruct. What is the right way to resolve the runtime type of DataStruct?
   In [python hints manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) it's written: *At runtime, isinstance(x, T) will raise TypeError. In general, isinstance() and issubclass() should not be used with types.* I believe the same issue is here.

   I can use *type(self).**orig_bases**[0].**args**[0]* to infer DataStruct, but it is conceptually incorrect. It will retrieve the first generic argument instead DataStruct. So, if a MetaDataStruct base class signature will change to *class MergedStruct(Struct, Generic[MetaStruct, DataStruct])* (swapped TypeVar arguments), MetaStruct will be retrieved instead DataStruct.
2. For some reason, when I tried to intialize *Document(part=1)*, it passed. In practice I expected the code to raise TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't do type checking at runtime; you need to use a static analysis tool like `mypy`.  Running mypy over the code you've given shows these errors:

```
22: error: 'DataStruct' is a type variable and only valid in type context
23: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[DataStruct, MetaStruct]", variable has type "Optional[DataStruct]")
24: error: 'MetaStruct' is a type variable and only valid in type context
25: error: 'MetaStruct' is a type variable and only valid in type context
26: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[DataStruct, MetaStruct]", variable has type "Optional[MetaStruct]")
27: error: 'DataStruct' is a type variable and only valid in type context
```

If you add a line trying to initialize `Document(part=1)`, you won't get a runtime error (there's nothing in your code that would raise an error; your `if/elif` will just be a no-op), but you will get a typechecking error from mypy that looks like:

```
54: error: Argument "part" to "Document" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Union[DocumentData, DocumentMeta, None]"
```

The problem with the `type()` check you're trying to do (and with an equivalent `isinstance`) is that a `TypeVar` has no runtime value, so you can't invoke it as a constructor.  See: [Instantiate a type that is a TypeVar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345608/instantiate-a-type-that-is-a-typevar)

One way to fix this is to require that the subclass provide the actual types:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractclassmethod
from typing import Generic, Optional, Type, TypeVar, Union

DataStruct = TypeVar('DataStruct')
MetaStruct = TypeVar('MetaStruct')


class MetaDataStruct(Generic[DataStruct, MetaStruct], ABC):

    @abstractclassmethod
    def _data_type(cls) -> Type[DataStruct]:
        pass

    @abstractclassmethod
    def _meta_type(cls) -> Type[MetaStruct]:
        pass

    def __init__(
        self,
        part: Union[DataStruct, MetaStruct, None] = None,
        data: Optional[DataStruct] = None,
        meta: Optional[MetaStruct] = None
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.data: Optional[DataStruct] = data
        self.meta: Optional[MetaStruct] = meta

        if part is not None:
            if isinstance(part, self._data_type()):
                data = part
                meta = self._meta_type()()
            elif isinstance(part, self._meta_type()):
                meta = part
                data = self._data_type()()


class DocumentData:
    pass


class DocumentMeta:
    pass


class Document(MetaDataStruct[DocumentData, DocumentMeta]):
    @classmethod
    def _data_type(cls) -> Type[DocumentData]:
        return DocumentData

    @classmethod
    def _meta_type(cls) -> Type[DocumentMeta]:
        return DocumentMeta
```

The above typechecks correctly (you'll get mypy errors if you don't implement the `_data_type` and `_meta_type` methods correctly in the subclass), and is able to use the class methods to call the appropriate constructors at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily, I used this solution:

```
actual_data_struct = getattr(type(self), '__orig_bases__')[0].__args__[0]
actual_meta_struct = getattr(type(self), '__orig_bases__')[0].__args__[1]

if part is not None:
    if type(part) == actual_data_struct:
        data = part
        meta = actual_meta_struct()
    elif type(part) == actual_meta_struct:
        meta = part
        data = actual_data_struct()
```